# Find percentage of first row within the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Day | Count  
----+------
1   | 59547  
2   | 40448  
3   | 36707  
4   | 34492
```

And I want it to query a result set like this:

```
Day | Count | Percentage of 1st row  
----+-------+----------------------
1   | 59547 | 1  
2   | 40448 | .6793  
3   | 36707 | .6164  
4   | 34492 | .5792
```

I've tried using window functions, but can only seem to get a percentage of the total, which looks like this:

```
Day | Count | Percentage of 1st row  
----+-------+----------------------
1   | 59547 | 0.347833452  
2   | 40448 | 0.236269963  
3   | 36707 | 0.214417561  
4   | 34492 | 0.201479024
```

But I want a percentage of the *first* row. I know I can use a cross join, that queries just for "Day 1" but that seems to take a long time. I was wondering if there was a way to write a window function to do this.

Comment: Your Postgres version? What have you tried? Define "percentage of the first row". And please use [formatting aids](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I'm using Postgres 9.1. Thanks for answering my question below, and the formatting tips. Looks like I need to study up on my window-functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your numbers, you may be looking for this:

```
SELECT *, round(ct::numeric/first_value(ct) OVER (ORDER BY day), 4) AS pct
FROM   tbl;
```

*"A percentage for each row, calculated as `ct` divided by `ct` of the first row as defined by the smallest `day` number."*

The key is the [window function `first_value()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html).

[-> SQLfiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d959/1)